# Grid view images are not get resized properly in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am working in an Android app,In this I need to design a screen using GridView .
In my case grid view images are not get aligned properly .I am displaying the gridview inside the fragment.

I want to arrange the images in a 3 column * 5 rows format.(without having scroll )

And I am using 512 * 512 pixels png format image

Comment: what is 3 * 5 format?

Comment: 3 column 5 rows 
I want to arrange the images in this format

Comment: set `android:numColumns="3"` in `GridView` in layout file

Comment: Please post your adapter and layout used in adapter file here

Comment: Please check the updated post @ChintakPatel

Answer (score 1):

You can define the rows and columns like this.

```
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:rowCount="3"
```

or you can do this programmaticaly as

```
 gridview.setNumColumns(nmrOfColums);
 gridview.setNumRows(nmrOfRows);
```

Comment: I am using 512 * 512 pixels images ex : icon.png(xxxhdpi)
is there any mistake in it ?

Comment: no no issue with image size chnage CENTER_CROP to FIT_CENTER.